# Unable to create ArrayList of Class in same Class

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestArray {

    public void function()
    {
        test1 a1=new test1();
        a1.setA(1);
        a1.setQueue(new ArrayList<test1>(1));
        test1 test2=a1.getQueue().get(0);
        test2.setA(2);
        test2.setQueue(null);
    }
    private class test1{
        int a;

        ArrayList<test1> queue;
        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public ArrayList<test1> getQueue() {
            return queue;
        }
        public void setQueue(ArrayList<test1> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }
        public test1(){}
        public test1(int a, ArrayList<test1> queue) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
            this.queue = queue;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to create `ArrayList<test1> queue;` in this code 
It is throwing below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at TestArray.function(TestArray.java:11)
    at test.main(test.java:17)
```

Comment: You're attempting to get something from an empty list.

Comment: `test1 test2=a1.getQueue().get(0);` at this point, there's nothing in the `ArrayList`, it's empty. `new ArrayList<test1>(1)`, the number here allows the `ArrayList` to "reserve" a certain amount of space for the internal cache, which helps with improving the performance of the `ArrayList`, it doesn't add anything to it...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these two lines

```
a1.setQueue(new ArrayList<test1>(1));
test1 test2=a1.getQueue().get(0);
```

What

```
new ArrayList<test1>(1)
```

does is create ArrayList with initial capacity of 1, it does not add any object to it

Therefor the queue in a1 does not have any elements and that is why you are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.